# I have an error in django template for loop

Tags: html, css, django, django-rest-framework, jinja2

I have an error in django template for loop.
My code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 form-field">
<label>Year</label>
<select name="year" id="year" name="year">
    {% for y in range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year + 1)) %}
          <option value="{{ y }}">{{ y }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
```

My error:

> 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for x in y
> range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year + 1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I solve my issue using following code:
 import datetime

 today = datetime.date.today()
        year = today.year
        year_dropdown = []
        for y in range(year,1899,-1):
            year_dropdown.append(y)

Pass key in render

return render(request, "add-ad.html",
                      {'year_dropdown': year_dropdown })

My html form django template code:
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 form-field">
                                    <label>Year</label>
                                    <select name="year" id="year" name="year" class="form-control basic-select">
                                        <option value="">Choose...</option>
                                        {% for y in year_dropdown %}
                                      
                                        <option value="{{ y }}">{{ y }}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use standard Python logic in templates.

Read [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/) about that topic.

The easiest way seems to create custom template tag filter:

```
import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_year_range(starting_year):
    return range(int(starting_year), (datetime.datetime.now().year + 1))
```

And use it in template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}

...
{% for y in "1980"|get_year_range %}
    <option value="{{ y }}">{{ y }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

[MORE ABOUT TEMPLATE TAGS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)